# How to Integrate SuiteCRM Web to Lead Form with Php..?

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/suiteCRM/service/v2/soap.php?wsdl");
$response = $client->__soapCall("login", array(
    "user_auth" =>
    array(
        'user_name' => 'admin',
        'password' => md5('223311'),
        'version' => "0.1",
    ),
    "application_name"=>""
        )
        );
$session_id=$response->id;
echo"Session ID".$session_id;
?>
```

> while i connecting it gives 404 error i need solution how to store form values to suitecrm

Answer (score 0):

You should use rest rather than SOAP.

ideally, your URL will be.

http://localhost/suiteCRM/service/v4/rest.php